# How to retrieve data in FIREBASE realtime database based on Latlng

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i'm developing android application base on Maps and using firebase database(google real time database free version) too.
but i can't retrieve data using latlng datas.

goals.

1. How to designs 'key and values'
2. How to retrieve data. using latlng.

( ex, -34.512 < myPositionLat < 14.235 && 24.352 < myPsitionLng < 64.234 )

help me lovers

Comment: Read https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html

Comment: you want to store location of what ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Design as following in Firebase Database

```
- maps
   -locations
     -U123456789
        -lat : 25.265
        -long : 25.32
     -U12345678910
        -lat : 25.265
        -long : 25.32
     -U1234567811
        -lat : 25.265
        -long : 25.32
```

You can retreive the data as by id suppose U123456789

```
DatabaseReference mapsrefrence=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("maps").child("locations");
  mapsrefrence.child("U123456789").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
                new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if(dataSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
                            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                            Map<String, String> value = (Map<String, String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

                        } 
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "getUser:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
                    }
                });
```